# Why use own currency instead of local in ATM or shops?

Tags: currency, atm

When I go to another country, the ATM and sometimes the card reader in shops ask if I want to use my own currency (DKK) or the local curency (€, PLN)

Everybody say it's the best option to use the local currency.

Is there any case where using my own currency is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any case where using my own currency is the best option?

Unlikely, but you can do the math at the register if you want. Basically, if you choose your own currency, the merchant and/or their card processor will use whatever exchange rate they want which would usually be less preferable than the standard rate used by your credit card issuer. The benefit, on the other hand, is that you'll see exactly how much you'll be charged in your own currency right there at the register.

Comment: I see the amount in local currency and in my currency, and I guess I won't be charted more when I select local currency when my bank make the conversion than the amount I see in my currency when the shop converts it.

Comment: With a receipt in my currency I can immediately file for reimbursement on a company trip. Otherwise I need to look online (but I prefer to limit my online banking access) or wait for the paper bill to enter the correct amount for reimbursement. But that is for corporate travel.

Comment: Say you have a bank account in the USA and buy an 100 Euro item in Paris. The merchant will get 100 Euro (minus some fees). Your bank will be asked to either send 100 Euro, or to send some number of dollars, that's what you were asked to decide. In your bank statement it may say "we were asked to pay 100 Euro so that costs you 108 dollars" or it may say "we were asked to pay 108 dollars". Except depending on who does the conversion, the dollar amounts may be different.